# Three columns with top block in each column fixed on scroll inside column only

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

I have three columns, in each column I have a number of blocks. On scroll the first block in each column should be fixed to the top. When you scroll down to the bottom of each column the first block should dissappear, when you scroll back up and hit the bottom of the column the first block should be fixed again.

Can anyone help me out. I'm using Vanilla JS

```js
{
var stick = document.querySelectorAll(".stick");

  window.onscroll = function() {
    stickIt();
  };

}

function stickIt() {
  for (var i = 0; i < stick.length; i++) {
    var sticky = stick[i].offsetTop;
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      stick[i].classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      stick[i].classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
header{
  height:300px;
  background:#ccc;
}
.block.stick {
  background: #333;
}
.block {
  height: 200px;
  background:#ccc;
}
section{
  height:1000px;
  background:#999;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.1.2/css/foundation.css">
<header></header>
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <div class="stick block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <div class="stick block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <div class="stick block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to take a look at CSS Flexbox.  You can accomplish 99% of your goal using only CSS. Once you get your layout, then it's as simple as toggle a class on the parent based on scroll position.

**Check out this great write up.**
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I can't use flex for this particular case.